# Expectation of exp(-1/(ax^2)) when x is a standard normal variable and a>0 is a parameter

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions

I would like to know if the mean value of $\exp(-1/(ax^2)) $ when $x \sim N(0,1)$ and $a>0$ is a parameter is known.

Comment: Could you perhaps formulate your question in a grammatically correct way?

Comment: This is an elementary integral which is evaluated in the same way as the integral of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp#

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-{\sqrt{2/a}}}$$ is what Mathematica says...

Comment: It should go to $1$ when $a\to\infty$.